# How to find next integer with same binary substring?

Tags: math, binary, substring

Consider the binary representation of two numbers:

```
5:  “101”  
10: “1010”
```

`“101”`  is  a  substring of `“1010”` but `“00”` and `“111”` are not.

Is it possible to find number containing a specific substring with math ?

Comment: What your are trying to achieve is a bit unclear, please try to rephrase it. Do you want to check if the binary string representation number `A` is a substring of the binary string representation of number `B` OR do you want to get all possible numbers whose binary string representations are substrings of a number `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish here, but *bit shift left* is the same as saying *multiply by two*. So if you want to get the "next" integer with the same "substring" you just multiply by two.

```
3: 11 
*2=
6: 110

18: 10010
*2=
36: 100100
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly the OP wants not only `"101"` as a substring but also `"01"` or `"010"`.

Answer (score 0):

Making a bit of jump on your methodology :P but you could convert the number to a string and use some sort of find method. It doesn't do it via math? but it gets the job done

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Integer myNum = 1010;
    String myNumString = Integer.toString(myNum);
    System.out.println(myNumString.matches(".*10.*"));
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I presume it's the OP specifically asks whether or not this is possible by doing math operations. Sucks that the reckless downvoting is becoming more and more common on StackOverflow